# Asymptotic progress bar for unmeasurable external process?

Tags: c#, vb6, progress-bar

What should a progress bar do when a program is waiting for an external process to finish and there is no way to measure its progress?

I note that this answer suggests a Marquee style progress bar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357655/327528

But what about having a asymptotic progress bar which get slower and slower, until it grinds to a halt due to the fact that pixels cannot get infinitesimally small.  Is this a good idea and how would you implement it?

Please give you answer in either or both of VB6 and C#.

Comment: Hum, not sure actually it'll improve the user experience.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the standard is to use a spinner if there is no obvious metric to determine how long the task will take. That is what I do, anyway.

Comment: Basically either form of ProgressBar tells you nothing that the "Hourglass Cursor" doesn't already signify. Just use that.

Comment: A progress bar getting slower and slower would give a bad impression to the user, I'd simple use an animated image ( like AJAX Spinners ) to show your application is busy and still working, just lets user know something is happening, instead of wondering if its still working.

Comment: On modern versions of Windows the "hourglass cursor" will take the fashionable appearance of an "AJAX spinner", "spinning wait cursor" or whatever. So (VB6) just do `Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass` and get back to implementing some actual functionality :)

Comment: @MarkJ: it's actually quite important because the process takes too long for an hourglass pointer but a normal progress bar halts about half way through waiting for an external process and the users don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

You should not such an asymptotic progress bar. You should use an "**Indeterminate progress bars**" instead (see following link).

Microsoft design guidelines for the User Experience (UX) give clear rules for progress bars [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511486.aspx):

> Use **indeterminate progress bars** for operations that require an
>   unbounded amount of time or that access an unknown number of objects.
>   Use timeouts to give bounds to time-based operations.

(Highlights by me.)

> - **Clearly indicate lack of progress**. The progress bar must
>     not advance if no progress is being made. You don't want users to wait
>     indefinitely for an operation that is never going to complete.

**[Edit]**

For better readablity, I hereby add my added information from the comments here.

A walkthrough in WPF: How To Implement [A Modern Progress Dialog For WPF Applications](http://jbaurle.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/how-to-implement-a-modern-progress-dialog-for-wpf-applications/)

Also, if you want to use an animation instead, Visual Studio delivers in all versions (except for the Express version, I think) an icon library with the permission to use these icon in your project:
[Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx).
You will have to extract them from ZIP format first, but I am confident that you will master this task.. ;-)

You can then find an GIF animation `status_anim.gif` in subfolder `\Animations`.

Comment: How do implement an indeterminate progress bar in C#? The link you provided describes it but doesn't show any code.

Comment: Craig - you seem to be making this overly-complicated for yourself mate. You have two choices - show a progress bar/loader or whatever that shows that something is happening but without any indication as to how much progress it's made/how much it has left to make, or you have the option of showing current progress. You don't have the luxury of deciding to opt for the latter without compromising a good  principle of UI design so you need an animation/loader/bar (your choice) that shows something is happening which will, preferably, loop smoothly.

Comment: @CraigJ: You can find a walkthrough complete with downloadable source code code at the following link. "How To Implement A Modern Progress Dialog For WPF Applications": http://jbaurle.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/how-to-implement-a-modern-progress-dialog-for-wpf-applications/

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: how do I get that animation with the workstation and the server with lines going between them?

Comment: @CraigJ: You could use the Visual Studio default animation which is included in your VS installation. See edits in my post above.

Comment: @CraigJ - what animation? Screenshot?

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: [MSDN Indeterminate Progress Bar Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511486.aspx#indeterminateguidelines)

Answer (score 1):

You can either represent progress or you can't. If it's an "unmeasurable external process" then you can't. So it's upto yourself as to decide what a progress bar could do, there is no 'should' - it's a design choice. In my personal opinion, a simple loop will do the job (a spiral?) - I wouldn't want my animation transitioning into something that could give the impression progress has been made by a measurable extent.

Edit: And I'm in no position to comment on whether a asymptotic progress bar is appropriate or not - I don't have a clue what it is.